# How to solve linker error of my sql client for architecture x86_64 for Perfect.org in server side swift?

Tags: ios, swift, perfect

I have just download perfect template with mysql dependency . and I am struck with linker error , see the following screenshots . [image]

I am running  the program with following configuration

1. Mac 10.12.1 macOS Sierra
2. xcode : Version 8.1 (8B62)
3. swift version

> swift version : Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6
>   clang-800.0.42.1) Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

Answer (score 0):

Please use Perfect Assistant to build your project http://perfect.org/en/assistant/ or read the Perfect MySQL document carefully.